# Alternative to FortiClient on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, ssl, ssl-vpn

I often switch between VPNs and FortiClient is a bit annoying because I can't remember my password and every time I have to copy-paste my long password. I'm trying to find some alternative to FortiClient to connect to SSL VPN as on following image (required data to connect is: login, password, port and hostname), but unsuccessfully.

[image]

Can you help, please?